# Xcode 4: HTML Preview

Tags: xcode4

I have a index.html in my project - but I shows everytime only the html code, not a preview. I found a lot of tutorials with the description, that I can set an editor in the file types tab of the xcode preferences. But this tab does not exist in xcode 4.

How can I change the setting, that every html file in xcode shows a preview and not the code?

Comment: I'm not sure, whether you can change the default behavior but you can open the preview. Right click on the file and select "open as->preview"

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but its not a real solution for me :)